# How many new addresses are "bad" on a credit report

Tags: united-states, credit-score, credit-report

I've heard that moving around a lot and changing addresses broadcasts instability on credit reports, and anecdotally, on credit scores too.

Can anyone quantify this for me, thanks.

ie. How much is too much, new address every 3 months? Every 2 years?

Does this affect the actual credit score? If so, in what capacity.

Does this affect lender's own and completely separate risk matrices?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When it comes to the [FICO credit score](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Credit_score_in_the_United_States#FICO_score), anecdotes are all you get.  The FICO credit score formula is a proprietary secret.

FICO has disclosed the basic components of a credit score:

- 35% Payment history
- 30% Debt burden
- 15% Length of credit history
- 10% Types of credit used
- 10% Recent inquiries

All this adds up to 100%; however, the formulas for each of these components are unknown.  Additionally, there may or may not be special factors that can add or subtract to your credit score; for example, money owed because of a court judgement may carry an additional credit score penalty.

Having said all of that, the conventional wisdom that I've read is that the number of past addresses does not affect credit score.

However, the past addresses do appear on your credit report.  And whether this is bad or not is up to the lender looking at the report.  For example, if you are trying to rent an apartment, and the landlord does a credit check on you and sees a new address every three months, he might not want to give you a 12 month lease.  A bank looking at your report to decide on a loan may or may not care.

I personally have an aversion to altering my life in order to try to game the credit score.  If you find yourself moving a lot, and you think this might be a concern for a prospective lender, a quick explanation about why you move a lot would probably help your case.